# How to get rid of $ attribute using JoltTransformJSON in Azure Nifi

Tags: json, mongodb, azure, apache-nifi, jolt

My example schema from the Mongodb database looks something like this

```json
{
  "_id" : {
    "$oid" : "5bd761deae323e45a93cddae"
  }
}
```

From here, I would like to simplify this JSON format using JoltTransformJSON processor in Azure Nifi

```json
{
  "_id" : "5bd761deae323e45a93cddae"
}
```

I tried this line of code in Jolt Specification in order to get rid of the **$oid** attribute

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "id"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but it seems to return java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception and cause it to be invalid processor

What should I do to remove the **$oid** attribute in the JSON file?

Comment: why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: Not an expert of Nifi, but have you checked out the MongoDB [$toString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/) operator?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the problem asked in my question by utilizing the FlattenJSON and ReplaceText processors

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yet, you can use **`JoltTransformJSON`** processor as already previously proposed like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the level of "_id"
        "*": "&1" // go 1 level up the tree to match the key "_id"
      }
    }
  }
]
```